# CSS only horizontal scrolling gallery wth images of various dimensions

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm tring to create a **CSS-only horizontal scrolling gallery** that contains **images of various dimensions**. Before you mark this as a dublicate (this question pops up frequently), I did do a lot of research and couldn't find any solution for different image dimensions yet.

My solutions so far have been:

1. flexbox
2. inline-block
3. [Peter Biesemans rotation trick](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/)

the flexbox approach:

```css
/* setting up the site */
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 8fr 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 8fr 1fr;
 grid-template-areas: 
  ".    .    ."
  ".  wrap  ."
  ".    .    .";
}
#wrapper {
 grid-area: wrap;
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
#wrapper ul {list-style: none;}

/* try using flexbox */
#wrapper ul {
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar; /*suggestion from https://iamsteve.me/blog/entry/using-flexbox-for-horizontal-scrolling-navigation*/
 height: 100%;
}
#wrapper ul li {
 height: 100%;
 flex:0 0 auto;
}
#wrapper ul li img {height: 100%;} /*<-- breaks the thing
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x1500"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x1800"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x1500"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

... but if I set the `height` of the images to `100%`, it breaks my neat gallery by introducing a lot of white space after the images. And because the gallery wrapper is a grid-item itself with no absolute dimensions, the only choice I have is to calculate the resulting height of the images in `vh` and that defeats the whole purpose of using `fr`. Am I wrong and is there a easier way?

The older way would be using `inline-block`, which has basically the same problem:

```css
/* setting site up */
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 8fr 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 8fr 1fr;
 grid-template-areas: 
  ".    .    ."
  ".  wrap  ."
  ".    .    .";
}
#wrapper {
 grid-area: wrap;
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
#wrapper ul {list-style: none;}

/* trying inline-block */
#wrapper ul {
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
#wrapper ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
}
#wrapper ul li img {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x1500"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x1800"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x1500"></a></li>
  <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The third option is just a bit too much of a hack and not ideal for mobile devices either.

So is there a slution to this?

*EDIT*: Features/properties the gallery should have:

- **vertical responsiveness**: if the browser height is reduced, the gallery's parent element is also, so it should follow along;
- **no minium or maximum image heights**; if the image is too small, it should be blown up;
- **horizontal response must be avoided**: if the width of the browser is altered, the image width should stay the same (according to the aspect ratio and the height of the image);

Comment: something like [this](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/QMzBEO)?

Comment: Nope, I want every image to be of the same height, but not the same width, so it should maintain its original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal alignment / centering of the ul */
  width: 1000px; /* for presentation */
  max-width: 100%; /* responsiveness */
  margin: 0 auto; /* horizontal alignment / centering on the page */
}

#wrapper > ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto; /* better this way */
  overflow-y: hidden; /* appears just a little, don't know why (yet), needs to be set to hide it and make it look nicer */
  max-height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper > ul > li {
  height: 150px; /* needs to match the height of the "shortest" img or be less than that but not more */
  flex: 0 0 auto; /* mandatory */
  max-height: 100vh;
}

img { /* responsiveness */
  display: block; /* to remove the bottom margin */
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; /* mandatory */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x1500"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x1800"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x1500"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It certainly got me closer to the solution, but it lacks some features I cannot miss this time: if the image height is less than the ``li`` it should be blown up. Furthermore if the browser window is changed in height, it should shrink the gallery too, because it is embedded in a responsive grid item. I'll edit my original post to point out these features, which I failed to express the first time.

Comment: Thank you! I am now trying to understand how the blank space is created, e.g. why and how the ``li`` element gets so wide in my solution, but in yours not. ``width: auto`` doesn't do anything. It' also not the original width of the image, so I don't understand how the engine computes this value.

Comment: Thank you so much, but no this is not what I meant. I am aware of this possible solution (see first paragraph after the flexbox snippet), but it is not as clean as I would like it to be. I was asking if there is a way so that the gallery could inherit its exact size and its items would adapt accordingly. If there is no solution, I would have to calculate the ``vh`` values of several layouts seperately in my project.